# An Abelian group that is not solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

I'm aware that every finite abelian group is solvable, but is there an infinite abelian group that is not solvable?

Comment: How do you define solvability? In my definition, $1=G_0<G_1=G$ is a subnormal series for $G$, as $G_0$ is normal in $G_1$ and $G_1/G_0$ is abelian.

Comment: That's how I'm defining it.

Comment: So, you see my comment proves $G$ is solvable whether or not it is finite?

Comment: So the answer is that all abelian groups are solvable by definition. (I have to admit that I asked the same question as a student when taking a course in finite groups!)

Comment: @DerekHolt Does a solvable group require a composition series with abelian composition factors? I ask this because this is the definition of solvable group given in Fraleigh, A First Course of Algebra. But if it is so, then infinite abelian group would be not solvable.

Comment: According to that definition all solvable groups are finite. That is certainly not the standard definition of a solvable group.